# Show that $|z+w|^2\leq (|z|+|w|)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am given that $Re(z)\leq|z|$ But I don't know how to get the result that is given in the question:  $$|z+w|^2\leq(|z|+|w|)^2$$

I have tried to substitute $z=a_z+ib_z$ and $w=a_w+ib_w$ but this just gets complicated and it doesn't seem to be helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|z+w|^2=|z|^2+|w|^2+2|z||w|\cos \theta\le|z|^2+|w|^2+2|z||w|=(|z|+|w|)^2 $ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two complex numbers, i.e. $\theta=\arg(z/w)$

Comment: The problem doesn't really involve any essential reference to the cosine function, or to the concept of an argument of a complex number - it's more elementary than that.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the inequality you have quoted, try using a few identities involving complex conjugates - it works out neater that way than by writing out all the real and imaginary parts, when it becomes hard to see the wood for the trees.

Comment: This is a comment.

Comment: Is there a reference somewhere on Meta that would explain to me clearly why my 'answer' doesn't count as an answer? I'm new here, but I could have sworn that I had seen other 'answers' like this one, and that they were even preferred for homework-type questions. Sorry if I've put my foot in it.

Comment: Check [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/rfc-social-norm-about-not-an-answer-just-too-long-for-a-comment-and-communit), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/posting-an-answer-as-a-comment) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/10473#10473). And don't be afraid of checking the meta posts for more information.

Comment: Far from being 'afraid', I've already checked (try to type links!): [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/answering-homework-questions-and-downvoting), [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13878/hints-for-homework-questions-reloaded), [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/problems-with-homework-questions), [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question/1804#1804), and the FAQ. Strong consensus seems to be that posting hints as answers is at least one good way to go. If not, it's still not clear why.

Comment: Write down your hint. Like my answer. If the OP has trouble you help him out.

Comment: Now I'm even more baffled! But we can't go on discussing this in comments. Can you explain it to me at more length elsewhere? Perhaps others might also be enlightened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21045/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-calum-gilhooley).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$|z + w| ^2 = \langle z+ w, z+ w \rangle$$

Use [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
|z+w|^2=z\bar{z}+z\bar{w}+w\bar{z}+w\bar{w}
$$
and
$$
(|z|+|w|)^2=z\bar{z}+2|z|\,|w|+w\bar{w}
$$
so your inequality is equivalent to
$$
z\bar{w}+w\bar{z}\le 2|z|\,|w|
$$
If the left hand side is negative, the inequality is satisfied. Otherwise we can square:
$$
z^2\bar{w}^2+2z\bar{z}w\bar{w}+w^2\bar{z}^2\le 4z\bar{z}w\bar{w}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(z\bar{w}-w\bar{z})^2\le0
$$
that is true because $z\bar{w}-w\bar{z}$ is purely imaginary.